# How to include links in blog post

Tags: django

I have built a blog with Django. In my BlogPost model I have a text field named "content". When I compose a blog post via the admin panel, any custom HTML (links, code blocks, external images) that I enter is rendered in the template as static, literal text - not it's true semantic HTML.

I want to create a blog that allows blog posts to use markdown. No one else is making posts except me, and there is not client-facing form throughout the entire site (except the admin login page). How do I turn off escaping so that I can use custom HTML like italics, bold, links, external images, h1's, h3's, paragraphs, etc in my blog posts?

I have been trying to find a resource to learn from but am coming up short. Should I use a preconfigured markdown app, or roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mark_safe` `django.utils.html.mark_safe` from view side
or in template you can achieve this by writing `{{your_field | safe}}`.
also you can use your custom template tag too for this.

Comment: Thank you! I was already using {{ my_field | linebreaks }} so this was an easy fix to change it to {{ my_field | safe }}.

Answer (score 0):

One way is that You can use [ck editor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) for admin to edit html with toolbar.

& You also need to mark as safe in template html otherwise it is rendered as plain text.

for example in template write below code:

```
{{ field_name |safe }}
```